# How can I simplify this Python loop code?

Tags: python, math, while-loop

I want to simplify, or reduce the lines of code necessary for it to work. The results are correct and the code works, but I'm inexperienced and have some unnecessary mistakes and variables, etc.

```
 s = 0
 M = 3
 k = 1
 while M <= 3:
     s += 1/(2*k)**2
     print(k)
     print(s)
     k = k + 1
     if k > 3:
         break
```

I included the if within the loop because it kept running without stop. I also wonder if the M variable is right to use here the way I did, or if there's a better option.

These are the results:

```
1
0.25
2
0.3125
3
0.3402777777777778
0.3402777777777778
```

Comment: You might want to tag the programming language, in order to attract the right experts.

Comment: If you expect others to find a more efficient algorithm you will have to explain what the goal of the program is. Using self-explaining names for variables would also help. Please see [ask].

Comment: I don't get this - the code works, but it contains mistakes? What does that mean?

Comment: @eng Please help me see your reasons for adding that tag which I removed.

Comment: @Yunnosch I didn't remove any tag

Comment: @eng On the contrary, you added one in your edit. I removed it. I would like to know what made you add it. A possible explanation is that you created an edit on an older version and by that undid the sensible removal of a previous edit. But in case you actually see reasons to tag this with that tag please explain. If accidental, please look out for this problem in future edits.

Comment: If you're code is working, and it sounds like it is, then the question is a good fit for a different stack exchange site, [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the 'M' variable as it is not adding anything to the code, so you can remove it. You can use the 'k' variable for looping, as you are already doing. Also you can use a single 'print' for formatting. The reduce code will be:

```
s = 0
k = 1
while k <= 3:
 s += 1/(2*k)**2
 print(k,"\r",s,sep='')
 k = k + 1
```

Answer (score 1):

A `for` loop can be neater.

```
s= 0
for k in range(1, 4):
    s+= 1/(4*k*k)
    print(k, s, sep= '\n')
```

Answer (score 0):

Practically independent of the programming language, if your loop condition is on `M`, but `M` never changes you have a problem.
If you end on `k` you should use that in the loop condition instead.

```
while k <= 3:
```

However, guessing by the fact how you init `M` and that `M` never changes in the loop, you might be looking for the configurable loop condition as provided by:

```
while k <= M:
```